# fade in webpage with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do:

```
#leftSide          #rightSide (display:none)
 _______________ _______________________________________________
|               |                                               |
| category      |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|               |                                               |
| category      |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|               |              content                          |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|_______________|_______________________________________________|
```

Every time I click on a link in a category, I want to fade in `#rightSide` with the content of that link.

I know how to fade it in onclick, but I don't know how to load new content every time without the page refreshing.

Any help appreciated, not necessarily called. Does anyone what this is called, loading content without page refreshing? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: +1 for easily explaining the question :)

Comment: You can do that through AJAX. Don't fade though, it's meant to draw attention to things the user might not see. However, if you fade a large box you're just taking a way a bit of their time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone what this is called, loading content without page
>   refreshing?

That's [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

---

---

As for your problem, assign `rel` attribute to your links that you have on left sidebar:

```
<a href="#" rel="div_1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" rel="div_2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" rel="div_3">Link 3</a>
```

Then assign `id` to `div` elements (which are assumed to be inside your content area) for each links with same value as their `rel` attribute:

```
<div id="div_1">Div 1</a>
<div id="div_2">Div 2</a>
<div id="div_3">Div 3</a>
```

Now with jQuery, you simply need to do:

```
$('a[rel^=div]').click(function(){
  $('#' + this.rel).fadeIn();
});
```

This way when a link is clicked, jQuery will read its value and will show corresponding div element in your content area.

Comment: +1 for embracing the "no network latency" principle and using the defaults. You might want to empty or hide (not fade) the other div though...

Comment: Wow perfect thanks, I'll give this a shot. Although I don't understand the jQuery you posted at all, could you explain what you did?

Comment: @eveo: `$('a[rel^=div]')` selects `<a>` elements that have an attribute  `rel` that starts with `div_`, that's a typical CSS selector. Then it binds a click event to it, such that if you click it will launch a function that you pass to it. When you do type `function () {}` without a name you have what they call a "callback", you can pass such callback to `click`. Inside this callback, you select the relevant div (by accessing the `rel` attribute of the `a`) and then fade that div in.

Comment: Ah okay got it, it works. There's a few things I want to add though. When I click on Link 1, div_1 fades in which is perfect, but when I click on Link 2, I want div_1 to fade out, then div_2 to fade in. I also had to set both to `display: none;` obviously. Thanks for the help. The problem I'm having now is I can't get the animations to sequence: `fade in-> fade out-> fade new page in`. Also, is that a regular expression: `$('a[rel^=div]')`?

Comment: @eveo You just need to add `$("#rightSide > div").fadeOut();` after the `.fadeIn();` line

Comment: No, that instantly fades it out after the initial fade in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. You'd handle the click event, pull the content in via AJAX/.load and apply whatever effects you want. Something like:

```
$("link").click(function() {
    var $content = $("#rightSide");

    $content.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        // Load content after transition is completed
        $content.load("aUrl", function() {
            // Show content after content is fetched
            $content.fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

Comment: More than two seconds of boring fading? Makes visitors close your site... o_O

Comment: Indeed that is far too long for the fade. That was the first number I thought of though. My personal preference would be no animation at all.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic implementation:

```
$('#left-list').on('click', 'a:link', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#right-side').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).load(href, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

But there are a few things such as updating your URL and such that you'll want to consider.

Take a look at this article: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/ - it covers loading in content with jQuery including preserving URLs.

Comment: Do you realize that if the content doesn't load in a reasonable amount of time that they'll be presented with a white box?

Answer (score 0):

I would immediately send out the ajax request at the same time as fading out `#rightSide`, then immediately begin fading in the new content when it is available.

```
$("#leftSide").on("click","a[href]",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#rightSide").stop(true,true).fadeOut();
    $.get(this.href).done(function(){
        $("#rightSide").stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

The benefit of doing it this way is the content begins loading instantly rather than when the rightside is done fading out and the content begins instantly fading in as soon as it is available rather than waiting for the previous content to fade out.

I don't suggest using animations for this scenario, but that's your call to make.