# Fade in content, then fade out, then fade in new content

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do:

```
#leftSide          #rightSide (display:none)
 _______________ _______________________________________________
|               |                                               |
| category      |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|               |                                               |
| category      |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|  -link        |                                               |
|               |     1. content fades in on link click         |
|               |     2. new link click fades out old content   |
|               |     3. new content fades in                   |
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|               |click -> fade in -> click -> fade out + fade in|  
|               |                                               |
|               |                                               |
|_______________|_______________________________________________|
```

Every time I click on a link in a category, I want to fade in `#rightSide` with the content of that link, then if I click a new link, the old content fades out and the new content fades in and so on so forth for all other links.

What I have so far works in the way that I click on a link, and said div fades in, then I click a second link, then the second div fades in right underneath instead of fading out the old div and fading in the new one.

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#div_1, #div_2').addClass('js');
            $('a[rel^=div]').click(function(){
                $('#' + this.rel).fadeIn();
            });

        });
    </script>
    <!--CONTAINER-->
    <div id="container">
        <!--LEFTSIDE-->
        <div id="leftSide">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="portfolio">
                <h1>blog</h1>
                <h1>portfolio</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" rel="div_1">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" rel="div_2">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <h1>photography</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>test</li>
                        <li>another</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--RIGHTSIDE-->
        <div id="rightSide">
            <div id="div_1">Div 1</a>
            <div id="div_2">Div 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--CONTAINER-->
</body>
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question and mark an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939384/fade-in-webpage-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, and? I wanted to take it a bit further and I don't know how so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Try [slidorion](http://www.slidorion.com/) It should do what you want, or pretty close to it.

Comment: Ah, i see. the answer doesn't quite answer it complete. I would have just commented and got it fixed there, you're only missing one line of code. `$("#rightSide > div").fadeOut();`

Comment: @KevinB All that does is fade it in, then immediately fade it in and then fade it out right after. I want it to fade out when I click on a different link, and then fade the content from that link in after the old faded out.

Comment: If you want one to fade in on top of the other one, you will need to use absolute positioning for at least one of the two objects to make them overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ijuveh/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('#div_1, #div_2').addClass('js');


$('.portfolio a').click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();                      // prevent dafault anchor behav.
  
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');           // grab our rel
  $('#'+rel).fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_1, #div_2').addClass('js');
    $('a[rel^=div]').click(function(){
        $('#' + this.rel).filter(":hidden").fadeIn().siblings(":visible").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

It doesn't fade out if you click the already active link, and it fades in and out both the new and old at the same time.

Make sure your divs are absolutely positioned as suggested by jfriend00 so that they are on top of each other. Otherwise, you will have to fadeOut first and then fadeIn after the fadeOut is finished.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_1, #div_2').addClass('js');
    $('a[rel^=div]').click(function(){
        var new = $('#' + this.rel).filter(":hidden");
        if (new.length) {
            new.siblings(":visible").fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
                new.fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** Only use one of the two scripts, not both.